# How to use a dependency as file object?

Tags: gradle

Is there an elegant way to use a specific dependency as a file object (cast dependency to file object).
It is often needed to pass a file as an argument to a task/ant task etc.
I helped me with 
   `configurations.myDependency.files.iterator().next()`
But this looks not very intuitive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you mean configuration not dependency. Assuming you have something like:

```
configurations{
  myConf
}

dependencies{
  myConf 'mydep:mydep:1.0'
}
```

Then, if you are confident there is going to be only one file in all of your dependencies for `myConf` then you can do `configurations.myConf.singleFile` (return type is `File`).

However, since configuration can contain multiple files, in order to make your code more robust you should iterate over all files in `configurations.myConf.files` (return type is `Set<File>`).

If you need to extract specific dependency jar from a configuration you can do something like:

```
configurations.myConf.files { dep -> dep.name == 'mydep' }
```

where `dep` is of type `Dependency` and the return type is `Set<File>`.

For more details see [Configuration javadoc](http://www.gradle.org/current/docs/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/Configuration.html).